# Typescript: Pass type into lib

Tags: typescript

I have some piece of code, that generates a type from a json file and afterward performs some operations on it.

```
import data from './mydata.json'

type MyType = typeof data
....
```

This way I generate a type that very specifically fits the json, meaning the type will have the exact same keys as the json.

E.g. this json

```
{
  "a" : "text",
  "b" : {
    "c" : "more text"
  }
}
```

will create this type

```
{ a: string, b: { c: string } }
```

Since I use this piece of code across multiple projects, I'd like to extract it into a library.
Each project has a different json, though.

Is there any way for me to pass the json from the project into the library, so that if I import MyType from the library it will have the exact keys as the json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)

So in my library I defined an empty interface and made the required functions use this interface

```
export interface MyInterface {}

export myFunction = (param: string): MyInterface => {
  ...
}
```

Within my projects I then override the interface with the type of my local JSON

```
import { myFunction } from 'my-lib'
import data from './mydata.json'

declare module 'my-lib' {
  type MyType = typeof data
  export interface MyInterface extends MyType {}
}

const myResult = myFunction('lol')
```

This way I can be sure that the functions within the lib operate using the type of my local JSON data.
So in the given example **myResult** will be of the type of the JSON.